# Layer "decoder" expects 1 input(s), but it received 3 input tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I'm trying to train an autoencoder (and actually the fit seems to go correctly). Then I want to test my models:

```
encoded_imgs = encoder.predict(images[:10])
decoded_imgs = decoder.predict(encoded_imgs)
```

where images is an array of images (224,224) and the latent vector is equal to 1024. I'd expect encoded_imgs to be 10x1024, but instead it is 3x10x24, which results in the error of the title when I perform the decoder.predict. Why the result of the encoder has that shape?

I'll add the structure of both encoder and decoder, while the predict uses the standard training.py library

```
latent_dim = 1024
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(224, 224))
x = layers.Reshape((224, 224, 1))(encoder_inputs) # add a batch dimension
x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.MaxPool2D()(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.MaxPool2D()(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Dense(4096, activation="relu")(x)
z_mean = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_mean")(x)
z_log_var = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_log_var")(x)
z = Sampling()([z_mean, z_log_var])
encoder = Model(encoder_inputs, [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name="encoder")

latent_inputs = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
x = layers.Dense(7 * 7 * 64, activation="relu")(latent_inputs)
x = layers.Reshape((7, 7, 64))(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, 3, activation="sigmoid", padding="same")(x)
decoder_outputs = layers.Reshape((224, 224))(x)
decoder = Model(latent_inputs, decoder_outputs, name="decoder")
```

If you think that some additional information is required to answer, tell me and I'll add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meh, you can see that the output of your encoder is a tuple of: `(z_mean, z_log_var, z)`. So you just need the last one as you decoder input.

```
encoded_imgs = encoder.predict(images[:10])[-1]
decoded_imgs = decoder.predict(encoded_imgs)
```